# How to convert a string into an object with javascript and return some keys in snake_case?

Tags: javascript, string, object

So I'm trying to to write a function, which takes an order as a string, and converts it into an object where the product will be the key. And the key value is the number of the ordered product in numerical form. Each item in an order always starts with the quantity of the product.

If the product name consists of more than one word,  function has to combine the words in the snake_case format. For an empty string, the function must return an empty object.

Can someone explain the best way to do this function?

**For example :**

```
myOrder('2 coca cola, 4 beer) // {coca_cola: 2, beer: 4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
function myOrder(str) {
  return str.length === 0 ?
     {} :
     str.split(',')
        .map(s => s.match(/(?<qty>\d+)\s*(?<name>.+)/).groups)
        .reduce((res, {name, qty}) => ({
          ...res, [name.replace(/\s/g, '_')]: +qty
        }), {});
}

console.log( myOrder('') );
console.log( myOrder('2 coca cola, 4 beer') );
console.log( myOrder('  46 foos & bars, 0fizz') );
```

Comment: nice snippet @blex!

Answer (score 0):

So i think i'll first split the string using the comma as divider, after that i'll have an array with an entry for each item.

After that i'll split it again using space as divider and get an array where the first element is the quantity and the others are the name of the item.

From here you can build up the object you need :)

Comment: Thank you very much!